# How to the picture of Gordon, Webb and Wolpert

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

[image]
**Q**
I am interested in the picture above, but I do not know how to graph it.
Is there any source about it ?

Comment: This is pretty easy with `TikZ`, even with my limited knowledge of `TikZ`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply create two `pics`, a square (`quadro` in my Minimal Working Example, by the way, learn how to build it for your next question) and a triangle (`triang` in my MWE), with an optional argument for rotation, and use them in a TikZ `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{%
    pics/quadro/.style={code={%  
            \draw[fill=cyan!90!gray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    }},
    pics/triang/.style={code={%  
            \draw[fill=cyan!90!gray, rotate around={#1:(.5,.5)}] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    }},
    pics/triang/.default=0,
    mymatrix/.style={
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    },
}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix[mymatrix]
{
\pic {triang={90}}; \\
\pic {triang={180}}; &\pic {quadro}; & \pic {quadro}; \\
 & & \pic {triang={270}}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\matrix[mymatrix]
{
\pic {quadro}; \\
\pic {triang={180}}; &\pic {quadro}; & \pic {triang}; \\
 & \pic {triang={180}}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with regular nodes, a squared nodes and an isosceles triangle with 90 degrees on apex angle. You can place nodes on absolute coordinates or using relative positioning.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    right angle triangle/.style={
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=90,
        shape border uses incircle,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=apex,
        minimum width=1cm*sqrt(2),
        miter limit=1,
        fill=#1!70,
        draw=#1!80!black,
        },
    tnw/.style={
        right angle triangle=#1,
        shape border rotate=135},
    tne/.style={
        right angle triangle=#1,
        shape border rotate=45},
    tsw/.style={
        right angle triangle=#1,
        shape border rotate=-135},
    tse/.style={
        right angle triangle=#1,
        shape border rotate=-45},
    sq/.style={
        minimum size=1cm,
        outer sep=0pt,
        draw=#1!80!black,
        fill=#1!70}
    ]

\node[tse=blue] at (0,0) {};
\node[tne=blue] at (0,0) {};
\node[sq=blue, anchor=north west] at (0,0) {};
\node[sq=blue, anchor=north west] at (1,0) {};
\node[tnw=blue] at (1,-1) {};

\begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,.5cm)}, node distance=0pt]
\node[sq=red] at (0,0) (a) {};
%use positioning before node specification to keep apex anchor
\node[below=of a.south east, tne=orange] (b) {};
\node[below right=of a.south east, sq=green] (c) {};
\node[right=of c.south east, tsw=blue] (d) {};
\node[below=of c.south east, tne=brown] (e) {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

Another definition of styles for the right angle triangle and square allow to simplify and unify the syntax and placement of elements. Both elements are defined with two arguments:

```
rat={rotation respect the apex anchor}{position of apex anchor}
sqr={rotation respect right vertex anchor}{position of right vertex anchor}
```

Some examples:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    %right angle triangle
    rat/.style 2 args={
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=90,
        shape border uses incircle,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=apex,
        minimum width=1cm*sqrt(2),
        miter limit=1,
        fill=blue!70,
        draw=blue!80!black,
        shape border rotate=#1,
        at={#2},
        node contents={},
        },
    %the square is a kite shape 
    sqr/.style 2 args={
        kite,
        kite vertex angles=90,
%       kite lower vertex angle=90
        shape border uses incircle,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=right vertex,
        minimum size=1cm*sqrt(2),
        miter limit=1,
        fill=blue!70,
        draw=blue!80!black,
        shape border rotate=#1,
        at={#2},
        node contents={},
        },
    ]

\node[rat={-45}{(0,0)}];
\node[rat={45}{(0,0)}];
\node[sqr={135}{(0,0)}];
\node[sqr={135}{(1,0)}];
\node[rat={135}{(1,-1)}];

\begin{scope}[shift={(4cm,0cm)}, node distance=0pt]
\node[sqr={-45}{(0,0)}];
\node[rat={45}{(0,0)}];
\node[sqr={135}{(0,0)}];
\node[rat={45}{(1,-1)}];
\node[rat={-135}{(1,-1)}];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0cm,-3cm)}, node distance=0pt]
\node[rat={-90}{(0,0)}];
\node[rat={90}{(0,0)}];
\node[rat={180}{(0,0)}];
\node[rat={-90}{(0,-1cm*sqrt(2))}];
\node[rat={0}{(0,-1cm*sqrt(2))}];
\node[rat={180}{(0,-1cm*sqrt(2))}];
\node[rat={0}{({1cm*sqrt(2)},{-1cm*sqrt(2)})}];
\node[rat={90}{({1cm*sqrt(2)},{-1cm*sqrt(2)})}];
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-4cm)}, node distance=0pt]
\node[rat={45}{(0,0)}];
\node[sqr={135}{(0,0)}];
\node[sqr={135}{(1,0)}];
\node[rat={135}{(2,0)}];
\node[rat={-45}{(1,0)}];
\node[rat={-135}{(1,0)}];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's easy with TikZ. The first image is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\definecolor{LB}{HTML}{5999D4}
\fill[LB] (-8.5,4) -- (-11.5,1) -- (-8.5,-2) -- (-5.5,-2) -- (-5.5,-5) -- (-2.5,-2) -- (-2.5,1) -- (-8.5,1) -- cycle;
\draw (-8.5,4) -- (-11.5,1) -- (-8.5,-2) -- (-5.5,-2) -- (-5.5,-5) -- (-2.5,-2) -- (-2.5,1) -- (-8.5,1) -- cycle;
\draw (-11.5,1) -- (-8.5,1) -- (-8.5,-2) (-2.5,-2) -- (-5.5,-2) -- (-5.5,1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

These things can be conveniently obtained by using `\clip`, `local bounding box`es and grids.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{dunno}{RGB}{113,154,210}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=box1]
  \draw[clip] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) |- ++ (2,-1) -- ++ (0,-1) -- ++ (-1,-1)
  |- ++(-1,1) -- cycle;
  \fill[dunno] (box1.south west) rectangle (box1.north east);
  \draw[ultra thin] (box1.south west) grid (box1.north east);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=box2,xshift=4cm]
  \draw[clip] (0,0) |- ++(1,1) |- ++ (1,-1) -- ++ (1,-1) -| ++ (-1,-1) -- cycle;
  \fill[dunno] (box2.south west) rectangle (box2.north east);
  \draw[ultra thin] (box2.south west) grid (box2.north east);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, perhaps even more convenient, use a `path picture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{dunno}{RGB}{113,154,210}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[GWW/.style={path picture={\fill[dunno] (path picture bounding box.south west) 
  rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
  \draw[ultra thin] (path picture bounding box.south west) 
  grid (path picture bounding box.north east);}}]

  \draw[GWW] (0,0) -- ++(1,1) |- ++ (2,-1) -- ++ (0,-1) -- ++ (-1,-1)
  |- ++(-1,1) -- cycle;

 \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
  \draw[GWW] (0,0) |- ++(1,1) |- ++ (1,-1) -- ++ (1,-1) -| ++ (-1,-1) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```